# Cannot convert from java.lang.Thread to entity.Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I writing web app and have 2 exceptions in my classes.

```
package entity;

public class Thread {
    ...
}
```

When I try to use instances of this class, as in

```
import entity.Thread;
...

    Thread thread = new Thread();
    thread.setContens(contens);
    thread.setTitle(title);
    dao.addThread(thread);
```

I get compile errors such as

> The method addThread(java.lang.Thread) in type ThreadsDAO in not
>   applicable for the arguments (entity.Thread)

and

> Type missmatch. Cannot convert from java.lang.Thread to entity.Thread

How should I fix it?

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of external sites

Comment: Can't becouse it will be to much code to approve an edit

Comment: Then learn how to reduce your problem into a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for advice i will do it

Comment: My guess is: you have a class named `Thread` and Java has one too, and you are trying to use one where the other is expected

Comment: I know, the easiest way to remove exceptions is change name of class and variables, but it should exist another method to do this without rename.

Sorry for mistakes, i don't speak english very well, hope you understand

Comment: Well, at least you know the easiest way to fix it. Next easiest would be to never refer to anything as a `Thread`. Use `entity.Thread` and `java.lang.Thread` universally, if you absolutely must call your class `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, package namespace is important. Specifically, the package `java.lang` is always included on the classpath and thus all classes in that package (such as `java.lang.Thread`) are basically "reserved" class names. As a comment above points out, you need to either change the name of your `Thread` class to avoid the collision, or you'll always need to use the fully-qualified name (`entity.Thread`) when you want to refer to it.

As a matter of style and readability, it's best to avoid class names that are the same as those in `java.lang` pacakge; so the option of finding a better name for your entity class is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your dao class. Looks like you do not have there import statement fot entity.Thread class. In this case java.lang.Thread is used.